# Running a python3 script but get NO Output files

Tags: python-3.x

I run a python3 script to read several image files.
It seems to run Okay, but I get no output files. After it executes the script I get this message that tells me that it processed the image file "Processed 8 images in 1.35s."
However, I also get this message:
C:\Users\xxxx\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py:219: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
"class": algorithms.Blowfish,

Did not know what else to try

Comment: I have no idea how you expect anyone to be able to answer this, without at least seeing the part of the code that is supposed to produce output files.  [mcve], please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.